# OpenLDAP on OpenBSD 4.6 -- no bdb?

Tags: openldap, openbsd

I'm trying to find any possible way to run my backend database for OpenLDAP on OpenBSD 4.6 as bdb. There is indication that ldbm isn't transactional and has data integrity issues. The OpenBSD community doesn't recommend running ldbm, yet dbd is also deemed broken since OpenBSD 4.3. What's the best solution to have a solid database backend to OpenLDAP on OpenBSD?

Comment: I know back-ldbm is "retired" as of a while back.  Not sure what's up with dbm on OpenBSD ("works fine on FreeBSD" :), but if you're in a crunch for a backend LDIF is probably safe-ish, and easy to migrate away from later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that you have two ways:

1. You can downgrade bdb, using makefile /usr/ports/databases/db/v3
2. You also can build openldap-2.4 from sources..

I think, it will be better, if you upgrade openldap. And if you don't want to build it from sources, you can make package for openbsd.

--

WBR, Ozerov Vasiliy